# descriptive div to my links

Tags: jquery, attributes

I'm trying to add a extra descriptive div to my links. The div should get it's information from the li a title attribute.

I'm able to get the title attribute but how do I pass it on to the div .omschrijving?

```
$("#sidebar li ").append("<div class='omschrijving'></div>");
$("#sidebar li a").each(function(){
    var hoverText = $(this).attr("title");
    $(this).text(hoverText);
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just to confirm: is this the effect you're going for? http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/popups/demo.html (This demo is done with pure css. There are ways to do it with javascript, as you're trying, but first I wanted to be sure that this is what you're after.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd grab the parent `li`, then find the `div` that you've just added and set it's text.

```
$("#sidebar li ").append("<div class='omschrijving'></div>");
$("#sidebar li a").each(function(){
    var hoverText = $(this).attr("title");
    $(this).closest('li').find( 'div.omschirjving' ).text(hoverText);
});
```

You might also think about combining these into a single method.

```
$('#sidebar li').each( function() {
    var title = $(this).find('a').attr('title');
    $("<div class='omschrijving'>" + title + "</div>").appendTo(this);
});
```